# Horseshoe shaped polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml, polygon

I have the following kml polygon:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>20.002,80.002 20,80.002 20,80.004 20.006,80.004 20.006,80.001 20.002,80.001 20.002,80.002 20.004,80.002 20.004,80.003 20.002,80.003 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

If I view this polygon in a cell in my fusion table, in the Table View of Google Fusion Maps, it looks like this:

[image]

However, in the actual google map, in the Map View, it looks like this:

[image]

The duplicate point has been rather annoyingly dropped. I want what's shown in the first diagram above, but how should I change my polygon to get the same shape in google maps?

I also tried with an inner bound, but no luck there either:

[image]

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>20.002,80.002 20,80.002 20,80.004 20.006,80.004 20.006,80.001 20.002,80.001 20.002,80.002 20.004,80.002 20.004,80.003 20.002,80.003 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I have the answer. I can add a tiny offset (jitter) to one of the two duplicate points in the polygon. However I must add the jitter in the correct direction otherwise the polygon becomes invalid and google no longer draws it. Looking at the previous points in the polygon loop, I should be able to establish in which direction I need to apply the jitter in.

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>20.002,80.002 20,80.002 20,80.004 20.006,80.004 20.006,80.001 20.002,80.001 20.002000001,80.002 20.004,80.002 20.004,80.003 20.002,80.003 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Answer (score 1):

Self-intersecting polygons require quite a bit of extra power to draw correctly, so they are not widely supported in all 2d rendering APIs / implementations.

I suggest you work around the problem by splitting your polygon into two pieces.

Comment: I've thought about doing this also, but as a last resort.